# Managing Maven project in Eclipse with git repository

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, egit, m2e

we recently migrated to Maven Build manager & git hub repository for our Java web-app.  Also i switched to eclipse as eclipse has good set of plugins.

As a new bie, i am simply running   **mvn clean package** from terminal at the code root directory. And then moving the compiled code i.e.,  /target/SNAPSHOT/* to tomcat/webapps/ROOT location.
And then starting Tomcat7 server. The process is time taking especially when i do code changes in Java & configuration .xml files.

I want to do it completely in IDE environment as i did earlier in Netbeans,  update code -> build and run in debug mode, ->  do code changes  and then commit.

Heard of egit & m2e in eclipse for maven & github integration, but not sure how to use it.

Please walk me through the steps required in doing so. I am completely new to eclipse.

--
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use Git for version control and Maven for dependency management and build automation. Once your project has successfully imported into Eclipse and recognized as a valid java web project, you don't need either Git or Maven in order to build/run it inside IDE. Just creat a server using you existing tomcat installation, add the project to server, then select `Run as > Run on Server`.

The Complete Guide:

1. [Creating a server](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user/topics/twcrtins.html)
2. [Adding projects to a server](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwaddprj.html)
3. [Starting a server](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user/topics/twsrtins.html)

For more details, check out [Testing and publishing on your server](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user/topics/cwover.html).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using `maven-jetty-plugin` http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin for running the webapp. You will not need to copy over stuff to tomcat. After configuring this plugin, you can simply run your application by doing `mvn jetty:run`

I generally do not like running webapps inside Eclipse. It's a personal prefrence, but it is always nice to have an IDE neutral way of building and running your applications. If you have `m2e` things should work simply fine. I have seen `maven-jetty-plugin` having hot pluggability where if you changed your web.xml, jetty would reload your application.